# How to connect jmeter with firebase

Tags: firebase, testing, jmeter

I want to use jmeter in mobile app load testing which uses firebase so i want to create connection between the test plan and the firebase and authenticate it so how i can do that

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab) - I don't think you can use it for performance testing.

In case you want to simulate hundreds/thousands of the mobile users which are concurrently using the application in order to see how your backend handles such situations you should rather mimic your application's network footprint in JMeter test.

1. Determine [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) which are used by your mobile app
2. Find JMeter [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which support these protocols
3. Come up with a test script which simulates real user using your app
4. Perform [parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization) and [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)
5. Run your test with increased load. If you prefer to stay with Google stack and don't want to run tests from on-premise machines you can consider using [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/) for launching your load generator(s)